# React App is taking a long time to load using Create-React-App

Tags: reactjs, npm, styled-components

I am currently attempting to use styled-components with Create-react-app(CRA) and in the past it worked beautifully, but now it barely works. The styling often doesnt refresh right away, and I often have to reload the page to actually see a change.

When I added a new component to App.js, my react application would enter a stage of continuous loading

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Main />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Main.js

```
export default function Main(props) {
    

    return (
        <p>Hey world</p>

    )
}
```

Navbar.js

```
export default function Navbar(props) {
    let result = sizeResult;
    console.log(result);
    

    return (
        
        <Header fixed flex align='center' fullWidth radius='0px'>
           <Container fill='none' size='lg' flex align='center' justify='space-between'>
              <Menu>
                 <Title>Kahoot</Title>
                 <MenuItem>Home</MenuItem>
                 <MenuItem>Discover</MenuItem>
                 <MenuItem>Kahoots</MenuItem>
              </Menu>   
               <Menu>
                 <Button padding='8px 12px' variant='fill' fill='#fff'>
                    <Subtitle size='16px' color='#46178f'>Create</Subtitle>
                 </Button>
                 <MenuItem>Fairy121</MenuItem> 
               </Menu>
           </Container>
       </Header>
    )
}
```

Terminal Output

> Compiled with warnings.
>
> src\App.js   Line 1:8:   'logo' is defined but never used
> no-unused-vars   Line 3:9:   'Container' is defined but never used
> no-unused-vars   Line 3:19:  'Button' is defined but never used
> no-unused-vars   Line 5:8:   'Main' is defined but never used
> no-unused-vars
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning. To ignore,
> add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

Comment: That's acceptable due to the way webpack does the work. If your project is getting bigger I would recommend using snowpack instead of cra (webpack)

Comment: This has never happened before though, it usually loads right away.

Comment: Is your project bigger than usual (for me i just switch off my device and it works fine after some time)

Comment: Nope, its smaller